# How to create a one note in a sharepoint document center

Tags: sharepoint, onenote, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have a user manual within a section of a one note notebook associated with my organization account and I need to share it with the rest of the organization.

I see that from one note I can only share the entire notebook, not just the manual section, and since I also have a sharepoint document center where I already share information, I was thinking of using it to host said manual.

When I went to create a new document I see that I don't get the option to create a new one note and I don't know if that can be enabled in some way, but when I try to copy the notebook from my account I don't really know where it is find the same.

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Editing New Menu you can add one note option
[image]